# Aiocache @cached decorator doesn't return the result

Tags: python-3.x, caching, redis, python-asyncio, nats.io

I'm using aiocache @cached decorator for caching asyncio NATS requests and i've got problem with returning data back to client
My code:

```
@cached(key="result", ttl=1000, cache=Cache.REDIS, serializer=JsonSerializer(), port=6379)
async def timed_nats_request(self, topic, msg, timeout=None):
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    msg = json.dumps(msg)
    response = await self.nc.nc.timed_request(topic, msg.encode('utf-8'), timeout=20.0)
    result = json.loads(response.data)
    if 'result' in result:
        return result['result']
    else:
        return result
```

Aiocache's @cached decorator caches my messages to Redis but doesn't return it back to client, so I mean I can find the cached data from Redis db but it doesn't return it via function (timed_nats_request)

My caches configuration:

```
caches.set_config({
    'default': {
        'cache': "aiocache.SimpleMemoryCache",
        'serializer': {
            'class': "aiocache.serializers.JsonSerializer"
        }
    },
    'redis_alt': {
        'cache': "aiocache.RedisCache",
        'endpoint': "127.0.0.1",
        'port': 6379,
        'timeout': 100,
        'serializer': {
            'class': "aiocache.serializers.JsonSerializer"
        },
        'plugins': [
            {'class': "aiocache.plugins.HitMissRatioPlugin"},
            {'class': "aiocache.plugins.TimingPlugin"}
        ]
    }
})
```

Help me, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found solution: I used always same parameter, so I should use key_builder without key parameter due to generate different keys :)